# API method to recursively make requests based on record count received

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I'm working on an API integration, and trying to figure out the best way to go about this.  The API request returns two array keys = 'recsindb', and 'recsonpage'.  I can make a request for a maximum of 500 records ('no-of-records=500', 'page-no=1'), but if there are any more records than that I would need to make a second request ('no-of-records=500', 'page-no=2').  I'm saving these records to a joomla database, so I'm not too worried about concatenating the two array sets together - I just need to make the call, insert it, and then do it again.

Here's where I am so far in my code....this works fine for the first 500 records, but I need some help figuring out how to make the next 500 work.

```
function getData($api) {
    $this->add("auth-userid", $this->params->get('auth_user'));
    $this->add("api-key", $this->params->get('auth_key'));

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://httpapi.com/api/" . $api . "?" . $this->buildstring());
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return json_decode($data, true);
}

/*
 * Methods used for building API URI 
 * For example, domain availability check allows multiple domain-name and tld pairs
 *
 * Example usage:
 * $qs->trigger('add', array('filter', '1'));
 * $qs->trigger('add', array('filter', '2'));
 * var_dump($qs->buildstring()); // filter=1&filter=2
 */

private $parts = array();

public function add($key, $value) {
    $this->parts[] = array(
        'key' => $key,
        'value' => $value
    );
}

public function buildstring($separator = '&', $equals = '=') {
    $queryString = array();

    foreach ($this->parts as $part) {
        $queryString[] = urlencode($part['key']) . $equals . urlencode($part['value']);
    }

    return implode($separator, $queryString);
}
```

And then to get the data, I would do something like this:

```
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('authentication');
$dispatcher = JEventDispatcher::getInstance();
$profile = JUserHelper::getProfile();
// Process the api plugin.
$dispatcher->trigger('add', array('no-of-records', 500));
$dispatcher->trigger('add', array('page-no', 1));
$dispatcher->trigger('add', array('customer-id', $profile->profile['customerid']));
$data = $dispatcher->trigger('getData', 'contacts/search.json');
```

Edit:
Still trying to figure this out, so I've pulled the above methods out into my local xampp environment instead of Joomla.

```
$trigger = new customClass;
$page = 1;
$records = "records.txt";
$fh = fopen($records, 'a') or die("can't open file");
do {
    $trigger->add('no-of-records', 1);
    $trigger->add('page-no', $page);
    $data = $trigger->getData('billing/customer-transactions/search.json');
    fwrite($fh, print_r($data,true));
    $page++;
} while ($page * $data['recsonpage'] <= $data['recsindb']);

echo "<pre>" . print_r($data, true) . "</pre>";
```

The problem with this way is that I'm getting 1 record 8 times (for each transaction in the db).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why I'm getting 1 record 8 times.  The method I'm using in the loop isn't being recreated each time, and so it's just adding onto what was already there, and so the API is only looking at the first set of requests to respond with.

I added a method to unset the parts array, and added it to the end of my loop...fixed.

```
function end() {
    unset($this->parts);
}
```